# SvelteKit SSR fetch() when backend is in a Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, vite, sveltekit

I use docker compose for my project. It includes these containers:

1. Nginx
2. PostgreSQL
3. Backend (Node.js)
4. Frontend (SvelteKit)

I use SvelteKit's `Load function` to send request to my backend. In short, it sends `http request` to the `backend` container either on `client-side` or `server-side`. Which means, the request can be send not only by browser but also by container itself.

I can't get it to work on both client-side and server-side fetch. Only one of them is working.

### I tried these URLs:

- `http://api.localhost/articles` (only `client-side` request works)
- `http://api.host.docker.internal/articles` (only `server-side` request works)
- `http://backend:8080/articles` (only `server-side` request works)

### I get this error:

From `SvelteKit`:
`FetchError: request to http://api.localhost/articles failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80`

From `Nginx`:
Timeout error

### `Docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  webserver:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    networks:
      - webserver
    volumes:
      - ./webserver/nginx/conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./webserver/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/:ro
      - ./webserver/certbot/conf/:/etc/nginx/ssl/:ro

  backend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./backend
      target: development
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - database
      - webserver
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app

  frontend:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      target: development
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - webserver

networks:
  database:
    driver: bridge
  webserver:
    driver: bridge
```

---

How can I send `server-side` request to `docker container` by using `http://api.localhost/articles` as URL? I also want my container to be accesible by other containers as `http://backend:8080` if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use SvelteKit's externalFetch hook](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#externalfetch) to have a different and overridden API URL in frontend and backend.

In docker-compose, [the containers should be able to access each other by name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59057783/315168) if they are in the same Docker network.

Your frontend docker SSR should be able to call your backend docker by using the URL:

```
http://backend:8080
```

Web browser should be able to call your backend by using the URL:

```
(whatever reads in your Nginx configuration files)
```

Naturally, there are many reasons why this could fail. The best way to tackle this is to test URLs one by one, server by server using curl and entering addresses to the web browser address. It's not possible to answer the exact reason why it fails, because the question does not contain enough information, or generally repeatable recipe for the issue.

For further information, [here is our sample configuration for a dockerised SvelteKit frontend](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/master/Dockerfile). The [internal backend shortcut is defined using hooks](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/ffa98fa23eab71dfe8e371caf21813273f41f27b/src/lib/config.ts#L90) and configuration variables. [Here is our externalFetch example](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/master/src/hooks/index.ts#L12).

Answer (score 2):

From a docker compose you will be able to CURL from one container using the dns (service name you gave in the compose file)

```
CURL -XGET backend:8080
```

You can achieve this also by running all of these containers on host driver network.

Regarding the http://api.localhost/articles

You can change the `/etc/hosts`

And specify the IP you want your computer to try to communicate with when this url : `http://api.localhost/articles` is used.